# How to compare and return multiple values in SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a SQL database with fields [ServiceDate],[CLID], [Reading], [DueAmt], [PaidAmt], [Balance] and [Status]. The idea is to choose accounts which have not been paid for the last 4 months and output the result to Listivew control using VB.Net (VS18 IDE). I need help with an example or reference on how to write this query from within Visual Studio IDE using VB.Net.

Most of other platforms I visited do not supply sufficient explanatory notes and codes to get what I'm supposed to do and learn from it. Also, I want the column for ServiceDate in the Listview contro to be formatted as short date, DueAmt, PaidAmt and Balance to Currency.

I will appreciate any help
Thank you.

Comment: VS isn't really well-designed for SQL query writing. Each SQL engine has a proprietary IDE that are (usually) much better (ex: SSMS for SQL Server). What part are you stuck on here? Writing the SQL query? Or setting the results to the listview? If you provide your existing code it will be easier to help. Also, which relational db system (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc.) are you using?

Comment: You should split your problem into smaller ones. You have a lot of different things going on. Start by doing a simple query and return the data. Then try to put that data somewhere. Then try to format the data. ect...

Comment: @JacobH I might say both. I'm stuck on writing the query to produce that desired result and yes again on outputting or displaying in the listview control such such that [ServiceDate] is formatted to short date, [Reading] to number, [DueAmt], [PaidAmt] and [Balance] to money. An example will be useful to me in this regard. I have a Listview control named lsvClients to display such result. Also, I have a combobox named cboFilters where I manually typed these filters to query various options. A common filter reads "View all unpaid accounts in the last 3 months ", if I can learn how to write a que

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed SQL Server, [ServiceDate] as a DataTime in the database and [Balance] as some sort of number in the database.

```
Private Function GetOldAccounts() As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * From YourTable Where [ServiceDate] < @d AND  [Balance] > 0")
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@d", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-4)
                cn.Open()
                Using dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                    If dr.HasRows Then
                        dt.Load(dr)
                    Else
                        Return Nothing
                    End If
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        Return dt
    End Function
```

I thought you would be able to find how to fill a ListView from a DataTable.
ListViews display a text property which is a string. If you need typed columns then look at the DataGridView which can be easily bound to a DataTable.

```
Private Sub FillListView()
        Dim dt As DataTable = GetOldAccounts()
        lv.Items.Clear()
        Dim lstAccounts As New List(Of ListViewItem)
        lv.BeginUpdate() 'keeps the control from repaintinng on every iteration
        For Each r As DataRow In dt.Rows
            Dim li As New ListViewItem()
            li.Text = CDate(r("ServiceDate")).ToShortDateString
            li.SubItems.Add(r("CLID").ToString)
            li.SubItems.Add(r("Reading").ToString)
            li.SubItems.Add(r("DueAmt").ToString)
            li.SubItems.Add(CDec(r("PaidAmt")).ToString("N2"))
            li.SubItems.Add(CDec(r("Balance")).ToString("C")) 'Will include the $
            li.SubItems.Add(r("Status").ToString)
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim s As String = i.ToString("C")
            lstAccounts.Add(li)
        Next
        lv.BeginUpdate() 'keeps the control from repaintinng on every addition
        lv.Items.AddRange(lstAccounts.ToArray)
        lv.EndUpdate()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Well, thanks for the code but how will I display the result of the function into the Listview control and having the control format [ServiceDate] as short date, [Reading] as number, [DueAmt], [PaidAmt] and [Balance] as money?

Comment: See update to my answer. If my answer was helpful, please accept as answer with the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.

Comment: Thanks Mary for your effort. I will try out the code and inform you promptly and if it works I will certainly vote your answer as appropriate. For now I'm shutting down my lab as the Sabbath is drawing nearer. I will be right back as soon as the Sabbath is over.

Comment: Thanks Mary, I went through your code and after following it carefully, I copied it like this: GetOldAccounts() function copied to module level so that I could re-use it anyway throughout the project, FillListView Sub procedure copied within the calling form and within a button click event procedure. I regret to inform you after running the code on many attempts, the function didn't return any value hence the listview control wasn't populated. I'm not sure if I'm missing something here either where to place the code or how to setup the listview control itself. However, I gave this answer a che

Comment: Check if the data types in the database match. Is ServiceDate stored as as Date or DateTime? Is Balance a number? Try running the query in SQL Server Management Studio. You might get an instructive error. Right after `If dr.HasRows Then` add a message box that says "We got rows!"  Normally, no message boxes for debug. If you can set a break point and step through, that would be better.